# tkinter widget doesn't appear

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to make a very simple tkinter app, but I can't seem to figure out why one of my widgets isn't appearing. The below code should render the string '30' in a row above the button-label pairs, but it only shows the button-label pairs and no additional string.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

data = {
    'projects': {
      'project': {
           'name': 'Project',
           'starttime': 0
    },
       'another': {
           'name': 'Another',
           'starttime': 0
       }
    },
    'clock': {
        'clockedin?': False,
        'time': 30
    }
}

def makebutton():
    row = 1
    for item in data['projects']:
        ttk.Button(frm, text=data['projects'][item]['name']).grid(column=0,row=row)
        ttk.Label(frm, text=data['projects'][item]['starttime']).grid(column=1, row=row)
        row = row + 1

root = Tk()

frm = ttk.Frame(root, padding=10)
frm.grid()

ttk.Label(frm, text=data['clock']['time']).grid(column=0, row=2) # should say '30'

makebutton()

root.mainloop()
```

If I move the '30' label line below `makebutton()`, it displays '30', but over the bottom button.

What am I misunderstanding here?

Comment: Right now both the `data["clock"]["time"]` `Label` and `data["projects"]["another"]["name"]` `Button` occupy the same location `column=0, row=2` of `frm`. So right now the label is under the button. Are you sure that both of them should be in `frm`?

Comment: @TheLizzard Adding an extra element for just the button-label pairs doesn't solve the issue - the external label still doesn't appear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are putting the label on row 2, and then in `makebutton` you're putting widgets in rows 1 and 2. Since `makebutton` is called after you create the label, the second button it creates sits on top of the label.

You should either move the label to row 3, or initialize `row` to `0` at the top of `makebutton`.

Comment: I'm an idiot and mixed up rows and columns. Thank you for pointing that out :P